# UIImage embedded in Launch Screen.xib not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application has a custom **Launch Screen.xib** file that has a UIImage that is centered and with a specific height and width maintained by AutoLayout constraints. The xib looks like this:

[image]

The image in the center is a PNG with no alpha channel.

My issue is that sometimes, when running on a device, the launch screen will look like this:

[image]

I have tried different image formats both with and without alpha channels and this problem will still occasionally crop up. It is intermittent, impossible to reproduce reliably, and very difficult to debug since the Launch Screen.xib is run before the app officially starts.

Has anyone run into similar issues, or does anyone have any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: Can you send me your source code, i will help you.

Comment: @thuanNguyen There's not really any source code involved here. The only portion of the app that is at issue is the Launch Screen.xib. The rest of the source code is proprietary and cannot be shared.